Chess.com AI says I lost opportunity to win queen but I can't see how

I moved e7 bishop. I can see the move suggested is better but can seem to see how it would win a queen

In general, the ChessCom game review's explanations are very dubious.

I imagine it means "win material worth as much as a queen" rather than literally win white's queen.
After 19 ... Qxg3+ (+1) you can quickly win the rook (+5), e.g. 20 Kd2 Qg2+, and threaten to win the bishop (+3) next. If white tries to defend it, e.g. 21 Kd1 Qxh1+ 22 Kd2, then 22 Nf2 is winning - the king can't move to e2 since Qc3 would be checkmate, Kc2 or staying on d2 without creating an escape allows Qd1++, and after c4 there is Qd1+ Kc3 Qd3++.
